# Custom UIButton, enabled property works but hidden property won't

Tags: iphone, uibutton, hidden

I have a little problem on my Xcode project (iPhone app).
I just modified the rounded rect UIButton I used before to a custom one but now the hidden property isn't working anymore.

```
if (artwork)
    {
    artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (256, 256)];
    shareButton.alpha = 1.0;
    shareButton.enabled = YES;
    //[shareButton setHidden:NO];   // Won't work, I don't know why
    }
else
    {
    shareButton.alpha = 0.0;
    shareButton.enabled = NO;
    //[shareButton setHidden:YES];   // Won't work, I don't know why
    }
```

I found a workaround, using enabled property and alpha instead of hidden.
But I would like to understand why the hidden property isn't working anymore.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to animate the show/hide? I believe the `hidden` property is not animatable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260652/animate-calayer-hide). A workaround in this case is to use the alpha property use the animation callback (`[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:]`) to set the visible state after the animation has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `shareButton.hidden=YES;`

Comment: Already tried this, did not work better...
Thanks for the reply though.